# How to expose customly built PyObject representing numpy array in PyO3?

Tags: numpy, rust, pyo3

I'm implementing a zero-cost wrapper which converts `nalgebra` vector to `numpy` array using `PyO3` and `rust_numpy` (I need this because by default `rust_numpy` exposes nalgebra vector as 2D numpy arrays instead of 1D and doesn't allow to share the vector between rust and python in the way I need).

The signature of conversion function looks like this:

```rust
fn pos_to_pyarray<'py>(
    py: Python<'py>,
    data_ptr: *mut f32,
) -> *mut PyObject;
```

It takes a pointer to the vector's memory buffer and maps a numpy array on top of it using low-level numpy API bindings. It works fine, but then I have a problem exposing a raw pointer to PyObject to Python. I tried something like this:

```rust
#[pymethods]
...
fn nth_pos_in_vector(&self, i: usize, _py: Python) -> PyObject {
   // Get the pos vector, the details doesn't matter here
   let pos = ...;
   // Creates a numpy array on top of pos vector data
   // returns a raw pointer to constructed numpy array
   // as *mut PyObject
   let v = unsafe{pos_to_pyarray(_py, pos.as_mut_ptr())};
   // Return PyObject
   *v
}
```

This fails:

```
#[pymethods]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoPy<pyo3::Py<PyAny>>` is not implemented for `PyObject`
```

I also tried to wrap it into a `Py` smart pointer or `PyResult` with no success - it emits errors that some of the traits are not implemented by PyObject.

What is the correct way to expose such manually constructed PyObject to Python?

Comment: does [`Py::clone_ref`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/prelude/struct.Py.html#method.clone_ref) work for you?

Comment: Please post the **full** error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: `rust-numpy` can do `nalgebra` vectors. You need to allocate the array via `rust-numpy` and not `nalgebra` (otherwise it cannot safely be zero cost), and get a `nalgebra` view via [`try_as_matrix_mut()`](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/borrow/struct.PyReadwriteArray.html#method.try_as_matrix_mut).

Comment: It looks like (although I can't be sure, because you didn't give us a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please do) that you are using [`pyo3::PyObject`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/type.PyObject.html), which is an alias for `Py<PyAny>`, where you should use [`pyo3::ffi::PyObject`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/ffi/struct.PyObject.html).